# Double dot .. in Delphi Map file

Tags: delphi, debugging

I have been inspecting Delphi generated Map files and I found one strange thing there. Identifiers delimited with double dots instead single one.

For instance `MapFile..TFoo` taken from simple example

```
program MapFile;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

type
  TFoo = class(TObject)
  public
    function GetFoo: string;
  end;

function TFoo.GetFoo: string;
begin
  Result := 'foo';
end;

var
  foo: TFoo;

begin
  foo := TFoo.Create;
  writeln(foo.GetFoo);
  foo.Free;
end.
```

and its publics map file

```
  Address             Publics by Name

 0001:00005AC8       MapFile..TFoo
 0001:00005BBC       MapFile.Finalization
 0004:00002BA0       MapFile.foo
 0002:000000BC       MapFile.MapFile
 0001:00005B88       MapFile.TFoo.GetFoo
 0001:000059D0       SysInit...
 0001:000059C0       SysInit...
 0001:00005AA8       SysInit...
 0001:000059B0       SysInit...
 0001:00005A98       SysInit...
 0001:00005A74       SysInit...
 0003:000007D8       SysInit...
 0001:000059A0       SysInit...
 0001:000059E0       SysInit...
 0001:000059F0       SysInit...
 0001:00005A04       SysInit...
 0001:00005A34       SysInit...
 0001:00005A4C       SysInit...
 0004:00002B98       SysInit..1
```

My best guess is that `MapFile..TFoo` is a class, but why double dots? And what is then `SysInit..1` As far as I know Delphi does not have anonymous classes.

Comment: Well, Delphi does have anonymous classes - they implement anonymous functions/procedures. But here exactly my guess would be it was TFoo's VMT. Something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/0kLZ0.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/eFpD3.png

Comment: @Arioch'The, those pictures show a `.map` file for C++, the conventions used are different.

Comment: @Johan the pictures do not show .MAP - as you can see in the pictures themselves. They show .BPL. And while I do not know which compiler EMBT uses inside the house to compile release BPLs - I think they use DCC32

Comment: @Arioch'The I am not so sure about anonymous functions... their entry looks way different than `SysInit..1`

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I do not think those entries ARE the anonymous classes either, I just said that they DO exist.

Comment: Regarding ..1 - try e-mailing Andreas of IDE FixPack. He made the units to recover string type for LLVM Delphi, and he mentions that system BPLs contain symbols that can not be generated by pure Pascal without binary patching or compiler magic. So i guess he knows more on this topic.

Comment: Ping @AndreasHausladen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ".." entries are references to the class-type or more correctly, the VMT for the class. A symbol is generated because the linker needs to identify it when linking together v-table ancestry and for linking run-time type information.

The compiler generates symbols which cannot ever be generated by the user's code. This ensures that the symbols are always unique and will never collide. Even temporary variables get a special name and an entry in the symbol table. They are actively skipped or ignored by the mapfile/debug info generation, but they are there.

Comment: But what are `...` entries? e.g.: `0001:0000E3A0       SysInit...HRESULT_FROM_WIN32`

Comment: Normally, I'd go look through the compiler sources for an answer... However, I no longer have that luxury so I'm only speculating here; I think those entries may be related to symbols linked in from object files (.obj).